# Error adding unique constraint: Column in table is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index

Tags: sql-server

If I already have a primary key on the column `Id` and I have a column `Name` on which I want to add a `Unique constraint`, how can I do that in SQL Server?

I tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Hotels ADD CONSTRAINT
        UNQ_NAME UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
            Name
)
```

Error:

```
Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Name' in table 'Hotels' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
```

`Name` is represented as:

```
Name nvarchar(MAX) Allow Nulls
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for this is:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD CONSTRAINT
        <constraintname> UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
            <columnname>
)
```